# Pick out specific text of a text file using regular expressions in SAS

Tags: sas, regular-language

I have the following data (or something of the like):

```
DATA test2;
INPUT STRING $31. ;
PUT STRING;
DATALINES;

James Bond is a spy
Hello World
123 Mill st P BOX 223
11 prospect ave p o box

P Box 225
Hello World
pobox 2212

P. O. box. 256
; 
run;
```

I would like to read only the lines that start with "Hello World" until the next blank line, such that my output would be

```
Hello World
123 Mill st P BOX 223
11 prospect ave p o box

Hello World
pobox 2212
```

My idea is to then do some manipulations on each of these two (or generally more) texts, and afterwards append them together. But first I need to only filter out the text I need. note that my original text file is huge, and where the spaces comes, I do not know.

My following attempt is this:

```
data test3;
 set test2;
 if _n_=1 then do; 
 retain startline endline;
 startline = prxparse('/Hello World/');
 endline = prxparse('/^\s/');
 end;

 if (prxmatch(startline,STRING)=1 or prxmatch(endline,STRING)=1) ;
 run;
```

It gives me the following output, but I need the rest also...:

[image: output]

*EDIT*: I should stress that it might be blank lines everywhere in the text, but I only want the information *between* "Hello World" and the *next* blank line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check for start and end separately and retain the flag.

EDIT:
This way only desired data lines are output. Concatenation has to be done in a separate step.

```
data test3;
 set test2;

 if _n_=1 then do; 
 retain startline endline start ;
 startline = prxparse('/Hello World/');
 endline = prxparse('/^\s/');
 end;

 if prxmatch(endline,STRING)   then start = 0;
 else if prxmatch(startline,STRING) then start = 1;
 if start then output;

 run;
```

---

With concatenation:

```
data test3;
 set test2;

 if _n_=1 then do; 
 retain startline endline start OUTPUT;
 length OUTPUT $3000;
 startline = prxparse('/Hello World/');
 endline = prxparse('/^\s/');
 end;

 if prxmatch(endline,STRING) and OUTPUT ne "" then do; /* check for endline - output string as observation and reset  */
    output;
    start = 0;
    OUTPUT = "";
 end;

 if start then do;
    /* Add text manipulation here */
    OUTPUT = catx(" ",OUTPUT,STRING); /* concat string */
 end;

 if prxmatch(startline,STRING) then start = 1; /* check for startline */

 keep output;

 run;
```

Comment: This does not give me the desired ouput

Comment: Ah, I see what you did, you concatenated the output into two lines... OK

Comment: When saying "append" did you not mean to concatenate the text? Also: should the hello world line be included or excluded?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was vague. That the hello world line is included is of no worry, although I wrote it in the post. As for the appending, I meant keeping the lines as I wrote in the desired output in the post, then doing some manipulation separately on the two (or more) bulks of text, and then appending the bulks afterwards...

Answer (score 2):

I think i get the desired output using this code.

```
 data test3;
 set test2;
 retain outputflag;
 if find(upcase(string),'HELLO WORLD') then outputflag=1;
 if outputflag then output;
 if string='' then outputflag=0;
 run;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing! Much appreciated!